# Rails money - create database column without currency default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

Can I use the t.money migration helper to create a column without a default currency?

```
  create_table :product do |t|
    t.money :price
  end
```

creates:

```
t.string   "price_currency",  default: "ZWL", null: false
```

but would like:

```
t.string   "price_currency",  null: false
```

Comment: If you really want control over that, why not do the migration manually like you're doing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set other default currency (I think `nil` is allowed too) in `money-rails` initializer as described [here](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#currencies).

```
# config/initializers/money.rb
MoneyRails.configure do |config|

  # set the default currency
  config.default_currency = nil

end
```

if it won't works try to specify `nil` for `default` key in `config.currency_column` option:

```
config.currency_column = { prefix: '',
                            postfix: '_currency',
                            column_name: nil,
                            type: :string,
                            present: true,
                            null: false,
                            default: nil
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the default

```
t.money :price, default: nil
```